# Can I read the allocation parameters of a dataset in zos using Rexx?

Tags: dataset, zos, rexx, tso, ispf

I want to create some Rexx code that allows me to allocate new data sets, in any format, such as PDS, Sequential etc.. by reading the data set information of an existing data set then applying those parameters to the new allocation.

For example, when I enter in a data set name in 3.2 and press enter I am provided with this information:

```
Data Set Name . . . . : HLQ.ETE.CNTL                                

General Data                          Current Allocation               
 Management class . . : MC000101       Allocated blocks  . : 6         
 Storage class  . . . : SC002020       Allocated extents . : 1         
  Volume serial . . . : VOL007         Maximum dir. blocks : 11        
  Device type . . . . : 3390                                           
 Data class . . . . . : None                                       
  Organization  . . . : PO            Current Utilization              
  Record format . . . : FB             Used blocks . . . . : 5         
  Record length . . . : 80             Used extents  . . . : 1         
  Block size  . . . . : 27920          Used dir. blocks  . : 6         
  1st extent blocks . : 6              Number of members . : 35        
  Secondary blocks  . : 2                                              
  Data set name type  : PDS           Dates                            
                                       Creation date . . . : 2014/04/02
                                       Referenced date . . : 2014/07/01
                                       Expiration date . . : ***None***
```

So in my Rexx I would like to do two things:

1. Read an existing data sets allocation parameters like those shown above
2. Allocate a new data set using the read in parameters

I would run this Rexx as part of a JCL batch job.

I would appreciate any assistance with this as I have researched for days and cannot see a way to do this.

Comment: Kevin's question is serious. A rexx program to run in batch to do what can already be done through JCL is asking for trouble. JCL already does it correctly, you need to write and get your program working, so it does something that already exists. What is the benefit you see in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If running under **ISPF**, the SPF command [DSINFO](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00%2Fdsinfo.htm) is easier to use as it setups variables for you.

If running under TSO, Kenny's answer of [ListDsi](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.ikjb800/listdsi.htm) is correct.

For ISPF DSINFO you would do (where the variable holds the dsname):

```
Address ispexec 'DSINFO DATASET('dsname')'

say 'dsn=' dsname
say 'volume=' ZDSVOL
say 'recfm=' ZDSRF

.....
```

---

Comment: This is the answer I went with because it allowed me to implement this in Rexx successfully just as I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the TSO function LISTDSI. That will give you everything you need.
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.ikjb800/listdsi.htm

Answer (score 2):

However, depending on what you're doing, I'd also point you to the DD LIKE parameter (for SMS managed datasets), or the DCB= option, for non-SMS managed datasets.  See  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/topic/com.ibm.zos.r11.ieab600/xddlike.htm and http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/topic/com.ibm.zos.r11.ieab600/iea2b690169.htm#dcbdsn for documentation.

Instead of writing your own REXX to go through and do this, why not take advantage of built in tools?  Especially since you say you'll be running this in batch anyway?

Comment: Great information, and great to know that I can also do this, thank you!